# Using command-line parameters as destination for cp and mv in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

I am attempting to do copy a file (or rename a file) by running the script with flags/parameters to give both the source and the destination file name:

```
#!/bin/bash/

while getopts s:d flag
do
        case "${flag}" in
                s) copy_source=${OPTARG};;
                d) copy_dest=${OPTARG};;
        esac
done

echo "Copy a file input with argument to another file input with argument"
cp $copy_source $copy_dest
```

The output is an error:

```
sh test_cp.sh -s  file1.txt -d file2.txt
Copy a file input with argument to another file input with argument
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘file1.txt’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

Does `cp` (and `mv`) not accept parametrized destination?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the mandatory `:` after the `d` in your `while getopts` line if the `-d` is to accept a parameter. Therefore your `copy_dest` is empty, and hence `cp` complains about the "missing operand". If you add "debug" lines such as

```bsh
echo "Source parameter: $copy_source"
echo "Destination parameter: $copy_dest"
```

after your loop, you will see the problem. To solve, simply add the `:`:

```bsh
while getopts s:d: flag
do
   ...
done
```

**Also**, please note that in particular when dealing with filenames, you should always quote shell variables, as in

```bsh
cp "$copy_source" "$copy_dest"
```

**In addition**, be aware that running a script as

```
sh test_cp.sh
```

*will override the shebang-line* `#!/bin/bash` and you cannot be sure that it is run under `bash`! If you want to ensure the correct shell is being used, you could either explicitly state

```
bash test_cp.sh arguments
```

or make the script file executable and run it as

```
./test_cp.sh arguments
```